# How to run a Ruby script with terminal options

Tags: ruby, bash, terminal

I built a LaTeX preprocessor in Ruby called [Vanilla](https://github.com/adhithyan15/vanilla). It provides a command line tool called `vanilla`, which uses `Optparse` to parse some command line options. I used the `OCRA` gem to compile it into an exe, which is only helpful on Windows. I want to do the same for Mac and possibly Linux. I know that Mac computers ship with Ruby and you can call `ruby vanilla.rb some options` to achieve what I want. But I am looking for a native way so that I can do `vanilla some options` in a terminal. Can anyone help me find any good tutorials on achieving this?

Comment: #!/bin/sh

ruby path/to/your/script.rb "$@"

or you can just use #!env ruby - just like https://github.com/iron-io/iron_worker_ruby_ng/blob/master/bin/iron_worker here

Comment: I added what you suggested on top of my .rb file. But when I try "vanilla.rb some option", I get two error messages. 1. require:command not found and 2. syntax error unexpected token `('. But when I cd into that directory and run the .rb file using ruby vanilla.rb some option it works really well. Do you know what's wrong here?

Comment: if you want to go second approach - you need to use #!/usr/bin/env ruby - shebang string tells how to run your app.

Comment: I did understand that. But I forgot to remove the .rb extension from the file. That's the reason it was complaining. But I ran into another error. This time I receive a "permission denied" error when I run "vanilla some option". What do you make of this?

Comment: I got it working! Thanks for you insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move the script to a folder named `bin` in your project directory, and take off the `.rb` from it. At the top of the file, put in `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`. You're done!

Comment: I tried what you suggested but when I run "vanilla some option", it says "Permission Denied". What does that message mean?

Comment: run `chmod +x ./bin/vanilla`.

Answer (score 2):

In Unix shells, the names of executables are looked up in a list of directories specified by the `PATH` environment variable. So, if you make your script executable and put it somewhere in the user's `PATH`, they'll be able to run it just like any other utility.

Comment: Hello Peter, I added the directory to path and I was able to get access to the Vanilla.rb after reloading my bash profile. I also added what "iced" suggested on top of my file. But, when I type "vanilla.rb some option", I get two error message. 1. require:command not found and 2. syntax error unexpected token `('. I checked several sites to find out what those error messages mean. But I was unable to get a clear understanding of what those error messages mean. But when I cd into that directory and run the .rb file using ruby vanilla.rb some option it works really well. What's wrong here?

Comment: Did you put `#!/bin/sh` at the top? Try `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` -- this will run the Ruby interpreter, rather than `sh`.

Comment: I only added #!/usr/bin/env ruby to the top but I forgot to remove the .rb extension. So that's the reason it was complaining. But I ran into another problem. If I run vanilla some option, I am receiving a "permission denied" error message.

Comment: Check your permissions on the file with `ls -l vanilla.rb`. If you see something like `rwxr-xr-x`, all is well -- this means that you can read, write, and execute the file, while other people can only read and execute. If you don't see that, try running `chmod +x vanilla.rb`. This will add the executable permissions.